# mdadm mounting array no such file or directory error

Tags: ubuntu, raid, array, mdadm

I used NAS system(Readynas) with Raid5 , but somehow trouble happened. 
So I connected every four disks to my Ubuntu machine and trying to rescue data.

```
$cat /etc/mdstat/mdstat.conf

ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=fd545cb6:345342544:7384acde:3847cad3 name=0e35cfc4:1
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=93129d53:adbc6384:cba5637d:34859482 name=0e35cfc4:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=06c043e4:55913070:bfdf08b2:6483ab43: name=0e35cfc4:1
ARRAY /dev/md/data-0 metadata=1.2 UUID=64b1f000:0b88551e:38b4a42b:d42dd5bd name=0e35cfc4:data-0
```

I think I need to mount md/data-0 for rescuing,

```
$sudo mdadm -R /dev/md/data-0
mdadm: error opening /dev/md/data-0: No such file or directory.
```

Maybe I must have some misunderstanding, but what can I do for mounting `data-0`?

```
$cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md1 : active raid6 sde2[0] sdd2[1]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/2] [UU__]
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[0] sdf1[3] sde1[5] sdd1[4]
      4190208 blocks super 1.2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

---

Thanks to @SYN, I could add the two disks to md1.
Status changed like this .

```
$cat /proc/mdstat
md1 : active raid6 sdf2[5] sdc2[4] sde2[0] sdd2[1]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 level 6,512k chunk,algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
```

---

Howeverm 1046528 blocks is too small for my purpose.

This is logs from my another Nas Hardware(same bland). It has `md127`.

```
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md127 : active raid5 sda3[0] sde3[5] sdd3[3] sdc3[2] sdb3[1]
      31236699136 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]

md1 : active raid10 sda2[0] sde2[4] sdd2[3] sdc2[2] sdb2[1]
      1308160 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [5/5] [UUUUU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sde1[5] sdd1[3] sdc1[2] sdb1[1]
      4190208 blocks super 1.2 [5/5] [UUUUU]
```

So I guess my broken one has lost `md127` somehow, is there any way to recover `md127`???

There is a `md127` under `/dev` directory

```
$ls /dev/md*
/dev/md0   /dev/md1  /dev/md127

/dev/md:
0  1
```

Comment: look at `cat /proc/mdstat` to confirm your arrays availability, edit your post including output, ...

Comment: I added /proc/mdstat data. there is no data-0 entry..... I remember that  when my nas server worked properly there were md0 md1 md127.

Comment: Looks like your md1 is missing 2 out of 4 devices. No traces of data-0 or md127 though. Looks like md1 is a raid6: you should still be able to recover it, re-adding the missing disks (or adding replacement ones). Since your md0 is still healthy, and considering it share two disks with md1, ... Have you tried something like `mdadm --manage /dev/md1 --add /dev/sdc2`, then `mdadm --manage /dev/md1 add /dev/sdf2`?

Comment: You are saving my life. I could add two disks to md1. it looks to work correctly. then... how can I mount this and reach the data???

Comment: Not being familiar with your hadware: maybe you will find entries in your `/etc/fstab`, referring to your `/dev/md1`. If so, just type `mount /path/on/the/left/column` to mount corresponding device. You might have to scan for logical volumes first (? unlikely, not impossible, `vgscan` then `vgchange -a y VolName`). In doubt: you should be able to reboot from there, and let boot process do whatever it used to

Comment: Thank you for your help. You gave me one step forward, but I have found md1 block 1046528 is too small for my purpose md* I updated my article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, re-formatting my comments as an answer.

The first step is to look for raid devices status:

```
$ cat /proc/mdstat
...
```

OP output includes:

```
md1 : active raid6 sde2[0] sdd2[1]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/2] [UU__]
```

This indicates that two out of 4 devices from your `/dev/md1` device are missing.

Now, since we can see that `md0` is healthy, using 4 partitions: two of which on the same disks `md1` uses, it is then fair to bet we can recover that array by re-adding partitions from the disks that are not listed as `md1` devices:

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 add /dev/sdc2
mdadm --manage /dev/md1 add /dev/sdf2
```

Reboot, in doubt, ...

Now, it appears we're still missing a third raid device ... You might be able to find it back using:

```
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Maybe:

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdd3 /dev/sde3 /dev/sdf3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help it is quit good advice for me and I could pointed out the problem.

Comment: `mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 /dev/sdc3 /dev/sdd3 /dev/sde3 /dev/sdf3` worked perfectly!!. The raid started with only 3 drives (maybe one drive was corrupted) thank you very much!!